# How to propagate callback promise value on Model.find( obj , callback)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback, mongoose, promise

Ok, I'm fighting hard this problem. I've spent a lot of time on the past week trying to figure out how to make this work. I've learned `promises` and made some cool stuff - and I'm love with it. But, I can't make this work.

I'm using Mongoose `Model.find()` method. This methods receives two arguments: an `object` that will be used to the query and a `callback` function that will receive `(error, data)` objects. I'm calling `.find` and passing `findUser` function.

```
UserModel.find(userObj, findUser)
            .then(userFound, createUser);
```

Inside `findUser`, I'm creating a `Promise` and resolving or rejecting it.

```
var findUser = function(err, data) {
    var p1 = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        if (data.length) {
            console.log('Resolved on findUser');
            resolve();
        } else {
            console.log('Rejected on findUser');
            reject();
        }
    });
};
```

But, whatever happens on `findUser`, the success callback is always called. On the console, I can see something like this:

> ```
> Rejected on findUser
> Resolved on find
> ```

```
var userFound = function () {
    console.log('Resolved on find');
};

var createUser = function () {
    console.log('Rejected on find');
}
```

**How could I propagate the promise value from `findUser` to `.find`?**

Comment: I don't know how `Model.find` works, but how do you expect it to know what happened to the Promise you created inside the `findUser` callback? At a minimum, you would have to *return* the Promise instead of just declaring it, right?

Comment: And this is why I'm asking. Did not know that. Trying it right now. I've changed it to return the new Promise. Same result.

Comment: Ok, you might want to try chaining like this: `UserModel.find(userObj).then(findUser)` but make it so that `findUser` is Promise-resolution style and takes just the (data) instead of (err, data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this. All changes in your code are commented.

```
// Remove err argument
var findUser = function(data) {
    // Instead of creating a new Promise, 
    // we return a value to resolve
    // or throw a value to reject.
    if (data.length) {
        console.log('Resolved on findUser');
        // Resolve this Promise with data.
        return data;
    } else {
        var reason = 'Rejected on findUser';
        console.log(reason);
        // Reject this Promise with reason.
        throw reason;
    }
};

// Function gets data passed to it.
var userFound = function(data) {
    console.log('Resolved on find');
};

// Function gets reason passed to it.
var createUser = function(reason) {
    console.log('Rejected on find');
};

// Promises will chain and propagate errors as necessary.
UserModel.find(userObj)
.then(findUser)
.then(userFound)
.catch(createUser);
```

Comment: Wow, it gracefully worked! Thanks. One question, if you don't mind. I know that Model.find() takes, as second argument, a function that will be sent 2 arguments and the first is the error object. How does this code send the first argument as data?

Comment: @Rodmentou One great thing about Promises is that there is no more convolution between `err` and `data`. Instead of having one function that confusingly has to handle both, we simplify it and have two functions, one for the `data`, and one for the `err`. On success, the `Model.find` Promise will say "ok we succeeded, so we only need to call the success callbacks with data, ignore error callbacks", so `findUserErr` never gets called and `findUser` does. In case of an error, the exact opposite thing would happen. Because of that, we only need one argument, which is the data.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've made my day. Week*.

Comment: @Rodmentou Happy to help.